# Find the two last digits of $[(29+\sqrt{21})^{2000}]$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $n=\left[(29+\sqrt{21})^{2000}\right]$. I want to find the two last digits of $n$. I known that, $S_k=(29+\sqrt{21})^{2000}+(29-\sqrt{21})^{2000}$ is integer, but from this I could not find the integer part of $(29+\sqrt{21})^{2000}$.

How to find them?

Comment: You don't need the full integer part, only the last two digits of the integer part.

Comment: You might be able to use $21\equiv 11^2\pmod{100}.$ Not sure how.

Comment: This is a bit nasty.  Knowing $\sqrt{21}$ in the $2$-adics and $5$-adics doesn't really give you the answer, e.g. $\sqrt{21}$ itself, from $\pm 11,\pm 39\pmod{100}$ doesn't recover $\lceil\sqrt{21}\rceil=5$ or $\lfloor\sqrt{21}\rfloor=4$.

Comment: Anyway, $\lfloor (29+\sqrt{21})^n\rfloor\mod 100$ doesn't appear to have a periodic structure.  [WA table list](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BMod%5BIntegerPart%5B%2829+%2B+Sqrt%5B21%5D%29%5En%5D%2C+100%5D%2C+%7Bn%2C+1%2C+2000%7D%5D)

Comment: $(29+\sqrt{21})^{2000}=29^{2000}+(\sqrt {21})^{2000}+2000 m$

$21^8\equiv a61\bmod 1000\Rightarrow 21^{1000}=(21^8)^{125}\equiv b1\bmod 100$

$29^2=841\Rightarrow 29^{2000}\equiv c1\bmod 100$

$(29+\sqrt{21})^{2000}\equiv (b+c)2\bmod 100$

Comment: Quite often in this kind of question, where there is an easy answer, we have $|a-\sqrt b|\lt 1$ which means that the implied recurrence gives the closest integer to $(a+\sqrt b)^n$, at least after a few terms at the beginning. Here $29-\sqrt {21}$ is large, which makes it very difficult to control the non-integer part in any way.

Comment: There might be some approach where you calculate $$((29/29 + \sqrt{21/29^2})^n + (29/29 - \sqrt{21/29^2})^n \cdot 29^n \pmod {100} $$ but I'm not entirely sure how to make the fractions cooperate with the modulus .

Comment: $(((((((29+\sqrt{21})^2)^2)^2)^2)^5)^5)^5$

Comment: My two cents is to note that $21^2+20^2 = 29^2.$

Comment: Where did you come across this question?

Comment: Sorry, I gave an answer about how to efficiently compute $S_n \bmod 1000$, but I now realize that isn't the hard part of the question, so I have deleted it.

Comment: I have dropped a solution, working in the polynomial ring $(\Bbb Z/100)[x]$ over the integers modulo $100$, further working modulo $x^2-21$ is easy, it is a finite ring, the powers to be computed have an easy periodicity.

Comment: probably related to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4057856/find-the-value-of-lfloor-sqrt21-sqrt291984-rfloor-mod-100?noredirect=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the conjugate $29-\sqrt{21}>1$ and the lack of periodicity(*), your best bet is probably to compute the coefficient $(29+\sqrt{21})^n=A_n+B_n\sqrt{21}$, $A_n,B_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and a very tight bound on $\sqrt{21}$ using the convergents from the continued fraction $\sqrt{21}=[4;\overline{1,1,2,1,1,8}]$.  Note that while you can use the value $A_{2000}\mod 100$ you cannot take this shortcut for $B_{2000}$, so you will be manipulating huge fractions thousands of decimal digits long, i.e., a task probably best left for arbitrary precision arithmetics on the computer or else be prepared to have many sheets of paper even just to write down one step of the calculation (you need more than 748 full period, with more than 1500 decimal digits in the numerator and denominator just for $\sqrt{21}$.  Add another 3000 for $B$).  As you can see from [WolframAlpha list](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BMod%5BIntegerPart%5B%2829+%2B+Sqrt%5B21%5D%29%5En%5D%2C+100%5D%2C+%7Bn%2C+1%2C+2000%7D%5D), the answer WolframAlpha gives is 43, which my little python program(**) implementing exactly the procedure outlined above agrees.

(*) Even for $x_n=\lfloor (29+\sqrt{21})^n\rfloor\mod 4$ the sequence starts with
\begin{multline}
x_0=1, x_1=1, x_2=3, x_3=2, x_4=0,\\
x_5=1, x_6=0, x_7=3, x_8=1, x_9=1,\dots
\end{multline}
and we don't see $1,1,3,2,0$ again until $n=2500$ which gives
\begin{multline}
x_{2500}=1,x_{2501}=1,x_{2502}=3,x_{2503}=2,x_{2504}=0,\\
x_{2505}=2,x_{2506}=1,x_{2507}=0,x_{2508}=3,x_{2509}=3,\dots
\end{multline}

(**) Python program:

````
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

n = 2000
A = 1
B = 0

for i in range(n):
    A_new = 29*A + 21*B
    B_new = A + 29*B
    A = A_new
    B = B_new

def sqrt21_iter():
    """ return iterator for convergents (p_n,q_n) """
    c_old = (4, 1)
    yield c_old
    c_new = (5, 1)
    yield c_new
    sqrt21m4_ref = (1,1,2,1,1,8)
    sqrt21m4 = sqrt21m4_ref[1:] + (sqrt21m4_ref[0],)
    while True:
        for j in sqrt21m4:
            c = (j * c_new[0] + c_old[0], j*c_new[1]+c_old[1])
            c_old = c_new
            c_new = c
            yield c

old = False
new = True
myiter = sqrt21_iter()
while old != new:
    sqrt21 = next(myiter)
    old = new
    new = (B * sqrt21[0])//sqrt21[1]
    print(f'\\sqrt{{21}}={sqrt21[0]}/{sqrt21[1]}, B\\sqrt{{21}}={new}, floor(A+B\\sqrt{{21}})={new+A}')
outstr.append('Result converged.  Stopping.')
```
````

Answer (score 2):

Denote
\begin{cases}
S_k=(29+\sqrt{21})^k+(29-\sqrt{21})^k\\[4pt] 
R_k=(29+\sqrt{21})^k-(29-\sqrt{21})^k\\[4pt]
Q_k=\dfrac1{\sqrt{21\mathstrut}}R_k\\[4pt]
P_k=(29+\sqrt{21})^k(29-\sqrt{21})^k,\tag1
\end{cases}
then

\begin{cases}
P_k=820^k,\quad S_{2k}=S_k^2-2P_k=21Q_k^2+2P_k,\\
21Q_k^2+4P_k=S_k^2,\quad
S_{2k}=\dfrac12\left(S_k^2+21Q_k^2\right),\quad
Q_{2k}=S_kQ_k,\tag2
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
S_{3k}=S_k(S_k^2-3P_k)=\dfrac14S_k\left(S_k^2-63Q_k^2\right)\\
Q_{3k}=Q_k\left(21Q_k^2+3P_k\right)=\dfrac14Q_k\left(S_k^2+63Q_k^2\right)\\
S_{4k}=\dfrac12\left(S_{2k}^2+21Q_{2k}^2\right)=\dfrac18\left(S_k^4+126S_k^2Q_k^2+441Q_k^4\right)\\
Q_{4k}=S_{2k}Q_{2k}=\dfrac12S_kQ_k\left(S_k^2+21Q_k^2\right)\\
S_{5k}=S_k\left(S_{4k}-P_kS_{2k}+P_{k}^2\right)
=\dfrac1{16}S_k\left(S_k^4+210S_k^2Q_k^2+2205Q_k^2\right)\\
Q_{5k}=Q_k\left(S_{4k}+P_kS_{2k}+P_k^2\right)
=\dfrac1{16}Q_k\left(5S_k^4+210S_k^2Q_k^2+441Q_k^2\right).\tag3
\end{cases}

The table below by Wolfram Alpha contains the directly calculated values  $\,Q_k\,$ and $\,S_k\,$ which can be used for the formulas $(2)-(3)$ verification.

---

[image: Q(k) and S_k]

---

From $(2)-(3)$ should:
$$Q_{2k}=Q_k\sqrt{21Q_k^2+4P_k},\tag4$$
$$Q_{5k}=\dfrac1{16}Q_k\left(5\left(21Q_k^2+4P_k\right)^2+210Q_k^2\left(21Q_k^2+4P_k\right)+441Q_k^4\right)$$
$$=Q_k\left(441Q_k^4+105P_kQ_k^2+5P_k^2\right),$$
$$4Q_{5k}=Q_k\left(5\left(2P_k+21Q_k^2\right)^2-(21Q_k^2)^2\right).\tag5$$

Therefore,
$$Q_1=\dfrac{2\sqrt{21}}{\sqrt{21}}=2,$$
$$Q_2=2\sqrt{21\cdot2^2+4\cdot820}=2\cdot58=116,$$
$$Q_4=116\sqrt{21\cdot116^2+4\cdot820^2}=116\cdot1724=199984,$$
$$Q_8=199984\sqrt{21\cdot199984^2+4\cdot820^4}=19984\cdot1627376=325\,449\,161\,984,$$
$$Q_{16}=Q_8\sqrt{21\cdot Q_8^2+4\cdot820^8} =567\,618\,853\,262\,266\,388\,905\,984.$$
And now, applying $(5)$ for $\;k=16,80,400\;$ in the forms of
$$Q_{80}=\dfrac14Q_{16}\left(5\left(2\cdot820^{16}+21Q_{16}^2\right)^2-(21Q_{16}^2)^2\right),\tag{5$\text a$}$$
$$Q_{400}=\dfrac14Q_{80}\left(5\left(2\cdot820^{80}+21Q_{80}^2\right)^2-(21Q_{80}^2)^2\right),\tag{5$\text b$}$$
$$Q_{2000}=\dfrac14Q_{400}\left(5\left(2\cdot820^{400}+21Q_{400}^2\right)^2-(21Q_{400}^2)^2\right),\tag{5$\text c$}$$
one can check that the last decimal digits of the $\;R_{2000}\,$ correspond
to the condition

$$r=\left\lfloor Q_{2000}\sqrt{21}\right\rfloor \mod 200 = 110\tag6$$
(see also [WA calculations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=q%3D567618853262266388905984%2C+u+%3D%7B5%2C-1%7D.%282*%7B820%2C+0%7D%5E16%2B21q%5E2%29%5E2*%28q%2F4%29%2C+v+%3D%7B5%2C-1%7D.%282*%7B820%2C+0%7D%5E80%2B21u%5E2%29%5E2*%28u%2F4%29%2C+w%3Dfloor%28%28%7B5%2C+-1%7D.%282*%7B820%2C0%7D%5E400%2B21v%5E2%29%5E2%29*%28v%2F4%29sqrt+21+mod+200%29000)).

At the same time, by the periodicity
$$s= S_{2000}\mod 200 = 176.\tag7$$
Therefore,

$$n=\left\lfloor(29+\sqrt{21})^{2000}\right\rfloor\mod 100 =\genfrac\lfloor\rfloor{}0{s+r}2 \mod 100 =43.$$

Comment: I do a small typo in the formulas (3): it should for example read $S_{3k} = \frac{1}{4} S_k(S_k^2+63Q_k^2)$ hence $+$ instead of $-$. Etcetera for other formulas.

Answer (score 0):

We work in the rings
$$
\begin{aligned}
R &=\frac{\Bbb Z[x]}{(x^2-21)}\ ,\\
S = R/(100) 
&=\frac{\Bbb Z[x]}{(x^2-21)}\Big/(100)
=\frac{\Bbb Z[x]}{(x^2-21,\ 100)}
=\frac{\Bbb Z_{100}[x]}{(x^2-21)}
\end{aligned}
$$
I will denote by $A=\sqrt{21}$ the value of $x$ taken modulo $(x^2-21)$ in $R$, and by $a$ the corresponding value in $S$.
In these rings we consider the numbers:
$$
\begin{aligned}
S_k(A) &= (29 + A)^k + (29 - A)^k &&\in\Bbb Z\ ,\\
S_k(a) &= (29 + a)^k + (29 - a)^k &&\in\Bbb Z_{100}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
While the value $S_k(A)\in\Bbb Z$ has no easy human chance to be computed for $k=2000$, we have a fairly easy human task when working in $\Bbb Z_{100}:=\Bbb Z/(100)$, in the ring of integers modulo $100$. Over this ring the polynomial in $T$ with the roots $(29\pm a)$ is $T^2-58T+820$ and
the "norm" $820$ already tells us that we deal with powers of zero divisors.

So let us compute some powers of $(29\pm a)$ with bare hands, till some $4$-periodicity shows up.
$$
\begin{aligned}
(29+a)^0 &= 1\ ,\\
(29+a)^1 &= 29+a\ ,\\
(29+a)^2 &= 841 + 58 a + 21 = 862 + 58 a = 62 + 58 a = 2(31 + 29a)\ ,\\
(29+a)^4 &= 2^2(31 + 29a)^2= 4(961 + 58a +17661)=4(22+58a)\\
&=8(11+29a)=88-8a=8(11-a)\ ,\\
(29+a)^8 &= 8^2(11-a)^2=64(121-22a+21)=88-8a=8(11-a)\ ,\\
&\text{ so the positive powers of $8(11-a)$ are $8(11-a)$, so}\\
(29+a)^{4k} &= 8(11-a)\ ,\qquad\text{ and by conjugation}\\
(29-a)^{4k} &= 8(11+a)\ ,\qquad\text{ which gives}\\
S_{4k} &= 8(\ (11-a) +(11+a)\ )= 8\cdot 22=76\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
$\square$

---

This **human solution** finds the answer, and also explains how we can and do expect a periodicity for $A_k,B_k$ modulo $100$ with $A_k,B_k\in\Bbb Z$ from the representation $S_k=A_k+B_k\sqrt{21}$, after applying the binomial formula.

In fact, it remains to take the obvious linear recurrence relation of degree two for $S_k$, and thus for $A_k$, $B_k$ from its form in $\Bbb Z$ to its form modulo $100$, and see how fast we get periodicity.

---

And indeed, this result can be easily checked in [sage](https://www.sagemath.org).
I am always checking, but please stop reading if computer software feels annoying, a matter of taste.

```
sage: K.<A> = QuadraticField(21)
sage: S2000 = (29 + A)^2000 + (29 - A)^2000
sage: ZZ(S2000) % 100
76
```

Note that sage did the computation exactly, we can also ask for

```
sage: ZZ(S2000) % (10^40)
5666971642218782495869571574855291109376
```

to have some more digits.

Alternatively, we can work in sage in the ring $S$, as in the above solution:

```
sage: Z100 = Integers(100)
sage: ZX100.<X> = PolynomialRing(Z100)
sage: S.<a> = ZX100.quotient(X^2 - 21)

sage: for k in [0..16]:
....:     print(f"(29 + a)^{k} = {(29 + a)**k}")
(29 + a)^0 = 1
(29 + a)^1 = a + 29
(29 + a)^2 = 58*a + 62
(29 + a)^3 = 44*a + 16
(29 + a)^4 = 92*a + 88
(29 + a)^5 = 56*a + 84
(29 + a)^6 = 8*a + 12
(29 + a)^7 = 44*a + 16
(29 + a)^8 = 92*a + 88
(29 + a)^9 = 56*a + 84
(29 + a)^10 = 8*a + 12
(29 + a)^11 = 44*a + 16
(29 + a)^12 = 92*a + 88
(29 + a)^13 = 56*a + 84
(29 + a)^14 = 8*a + 12
(29 + a)^15 = 44*a + 16
(29 + a)^16 = 92*a + 88
sage: S2000 = (29 + a)^2000 + (29 - a)^2000
sage: S2000
76
```

Finally, here are some last digits of the first $S_k$, with $k\in 0,1,\dots,20$:

```
sage: def S(k):    return ZZ( (29 +  A)^k + (29 - A)^k )
sage: for k in [0..20]:
....:     print(f"S({k}) = {S(k)}")
S(0) = 2
S(1) = 58
S(2) = 1724
S(3) = 52432
S(4) = 1627376
S(5) = 51393568
S(6) = 1646378624
S(7) = 53347234432
S(8) = 1744109125376
S(9) = 57413597037568
S(10) = 1899819145370624
S(11) = 63110360860690432
S(12) = 2102549230716133376
S(13) = 70197359475769581568
S(14) = 2347356480407406362624
S(15) = 78584841093498512146432
S(16) = 2633088469488840487141376
S(17) = 88279561533683968294125568
S(18) = 2961082023972820961603354624
S(19) = 99353516932802761771811602432
S(20) = 3334416722444846994250322149376
sage:
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works... Why do you compute $B_k$ modulo 100? The congruence $B_k ≡ B'_k \mod 100$ doesn't imply $\lfloor B_k \sqrt{21} \rfloor ≡ \lfloor B'_k \sqrt{21} \rfloor \mod 100$.

Comment: Sage says the solution is 43. `floor((29+sqrt(21))^2000)%100 = 43`

Comment: The fact that $(29+a)^{2000} + (29-a)^{2000} \mod 100 = 76$  is very easy to prove. The problem lies in isolating $(29+a)^{2000}$ (or $(29-a)^{2000}$) and you did not succeed to do that.

Comment: @Idéophage Can you extract a linear recurrence with coefficients in $\Bbb Z$ from $A_{k+1}+B_{k+1}\sqrt{21}=(A_k+B_k\sqrt{21})(29+\sqrt{21})$ ? Either one of degree two for $(A_k)$ or one of degree one for the column vector with components $A_k$, $B_k$... Yes, this is not $S_k$, i will edit... but it is enough to get $S_k$

Comment: @Maestro13 What does it mean to "isolate them"? The question is *unclear* as stated. Do you want the last two digits of the number $S_k$, please make clear what does it mean to "isolate" $(29+a)^{2000}$. I have computed that number.

Comment: The question is to determine the last two digits of the integer part of $(29+a)^{2000}$

Comment: @Maestro13 ... oh, my first impression was that the OP wants to compute the integer $$ (29 +\sqrt{21})^{2000} + (29 -\sqrt{21})^{2000} $$ taken modulo $100$. In this case, i have to start again... i see only numerical ways to proceed now, will edit the above...